# Syntax Coloring Not Working as Expected in VIM Editor 6.3 on AIX 5.3

Tags: linux, vim, editor, vi, aix

I enabled syntax highlighting for my C files by issuing the command `:syntax on`. I expected it to change the colors of keywords etc. But to my surprise, syntax highlighting is happening, but all keywords are being underlined instead of being colored!

Am I missing out something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the problem is not with `vim` as such. The problem is with the terminals I am using. According to [VIM Documentation](http://www.usf.uos.de/infoservice/doc/localhtml/vim/syntax.html#highlight-args), the terminals I was using, `vt100` and `xterm` don't support colors! And hence no colors in `vim` too!

But to my surprise, on another server, `xterm` seemed to support 8 colors. I found this by running `/usr/bin/tput colors` which outputted `-1` on the server where there were no colors and `8` on the server which supported colors.

Thanks to @Idigas for the appropriate pointers!

Comment: Just saw your last reply - a little late, though. But glad to hear you solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not. If `syntax on` is changing the looks of your buffer to something different than what you expect, you might want to check out the contents of your colortheme.

Try `:echo g:colors_name` to see which one it is, and then editing the aforementioned file.

Also, `:hi Normal` and let's say, `:hi Comment` and see how it looks in there.

Comment: @Idigas, When I tried `:echo g:colors_name` it said undefined variable g:colors_name. I did some googling and found a few colors scheme here-http://vimcolorschemetest.googlecode.com/svn/html/index-c.html. I picked up one of them (dante), placed it inside `~/.vim/colors` as `dante.vim` and added `colorscheme dante` in my .vimrc. Now, `:echo g:colors_name` says `dante` but still no effect. I wonder whether my terminal supports colors in the first place?

Comment: @Idigas, One more curious thing I found is that in my colorscheme `dante.vim`, `hi Comment` corresponds to `term=bold ctermfg=darkcyan guifg=cyan4` but when I say `:hi Comment` from command mode of vim, it says `Comment        xxx term=bold ctermfg=3`. Is the missing out of `guifg` the problem?

Comment: @PavanManjunath - Most colorschemes use g:colors_name as their identifier. What terminal are you using btw? Is anything happening when you write ":hi Normal ctermbg=15"

Comment: @PavanManjunath - No, the guifg is only relevant if you're running GUI Vim (GVim). You should be looking for colorschemes that have "ctermbg/fg" and "termfg/bg" values in them. GUI and console (term) versions of colorschemes are sometimes completely different because the term cannot support (usually, does not) that many colors as the GUI.

Comment: @Idigas, I am using vt100 terminal. And when I say `:hi Normal ctermbg=15` nothing seems to be happening wrt colors! Also a new peculiar problem I am observing occasionally when I say `:syntax on` is that strange characters like `^[[35m` are appearing all over! Even underlining is not happening!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
set term=ansi
```

to your `~/.vimrc` file to override your `term` setting for the duration of your `vim` session.

Comment: You just fixed my world :)